# Optimization problem: Calculate speed of rotating projector given the speed of someone that walks in front of it.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, optimization

So I was doing some exercises and I am stuck on this following one:

A guy is walking on a straight line at a speed of 1 m/s. A projector on the ground 6 m away from the guy is continually pointed towards him. At what speed is the projector turning at the moment where the guy is 4.5 m away from the closest point to the projector?

Comment: What have you tried?  Draw a diagram.  You project the $1$ m/sec on the perpendicular to the radius vector to get the linear speed and divide by the radius to get the angular speed.

Comment: I tried drawing the diagram but as to what to do with it, for some reason I'm just really lost.
[Diagram](http://i.imgur.com/or0BoMv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the $6$ meters is the distance of closest approach between the guy and the projector.  A diagram is below.  The projector is at A, the origin.  The guy's path is the vertical line and point C is 4.5m from B.  The guy's velocity is the vector.  Project the vector on the perpendicular to AC to get the way it is turning.

[image]